# How to access the body of a Request[_] as byte array

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.2

Accessing the byte array of a request body is straightforward as long as one uses the appropriate body parsers when defining an Action, like `request.body.asRaw...`.

However, I'm building an `ActionBuilder` for HMAC-secured Actions right now, where access to the body is inevitable. The Problem is that the definition of ActionBuilders is generic in terms of the request type and thus also of the body parser:

```
def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: HmacRequest[A] => Future[SimpleResult])
```

As `A` doesn't have any type constraints, there doesn't seem to be any way to get access to the request body from a `Request[_]`.

In my specific case, it would work to do something like:

```
request.body.asInstanceOf[AnyContentAsJson].json.toString()...
```

but that isn't an acceptable solution for me.

I also tried defining a custom body parser and applying it to the `Request[_]`, but the results turned out empty.

**How do I get access to the body of a `Request[_]` (a byte array representation would suffice)?**

---

Update: it would also be an acceptable solution if I can get access to the request body within the `ActionBuilder`, for instance through wrapping the whole processing in another action that does custom parsing. But I don't see how that would work... The solution should be reusable in the sense that arbitrary user-defined actions can be used along with the HMAC-functionality, without interfering with any of the user logic.

Answer (score 3):

The way we solved this (in Play 2.3) is to construct a BodyParser which runs 2 BodyParsers in parallel. Using this you can run a BodyParsers.parse.raw or whatever in addition to your main one. Combine the raw parser with validation (not shown here), and produce a Left[Result] with any error message and status you like, to achieve your desired result.

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext    

import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.defaultContext
import play.api.libs.iteratee.Enumeratee
import play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee
import play.api.mvc.BodyParser
import play.api.mvc.RequestHeader
import play.api.mvc.Result  

/**
 * A BodyParser which executes any two provided BodyParsers in parallel.
 *
 * The results are combined in the following way:
 * If any wrapped parser's Iteratee encounters an Error, that's the result.
 * Else if the first parser's Iteratee finally yields a Left, this is used as the result.
 * Else if the second parser's Iteratee yields a Left, this is used as the result.
 * Else both Right results are combined in a Right[(A, B)].
 *
 * This can be used to e.g. provide the request's body both as a RawBuffer and a json-parsed
 * custom model class, or to feed the body through a HMAC module in addition to parsing it.
 *
 * @author Jürgen Strobel <juergen@strobel.info>
 */
final case class DualBodyParser[+A, +B](
    a: BodyParser[A],
    b: BodyParser[B]
)(
    implicit ec: ExecutionContext = defaultContext
)
extends BodyParser[(A, B)]
{
    def apply(v1: RequestHeader): Iteratee[Array[Byte], Either[Result, (A, B)]] =
        Enumeratee.zipWith(a(v1), b(v1)) {
            case (Left(va), _) => Left(va)
            case (_, Left(vb)) => Left(vb)
            case (Right(va), Right(vb)) => Right((va, vb))
        }
}
```

We also created a custom variant of ActionBuilder which wraps any user provided BodyParser with a DualBodyParser and our own validation logic, and splices out the result from the second one again to the user-provided code block only after authentication has succeeded. Note this variation on ActionBuilder copy&pastes much of the original ActionBuilder code, but takes a parameter to inject our authentication logic, so it's a class and not an object. There would be different ways to solve this problem. Encapsulating the full authentication logic in a BodyParser is on the TODO list, and probably easier and better composable.

```
/**
 * An FooAuthenticatedAction does Foo authentication before invoking its action block.
 *
 * This replicates ActionBuilder and Action almost fully.
 * It splices a parser.tolerantText BodyParser in, does Foo authentication with the
 * body text, and then continues to call the provided block with the result of the
 * provided body parser (if any).
 *
 * @param fooHelper An FooHelper configured to handle the incoming requests.
 *
 * @author Jürgen Strobel <juergen@strobel.info>
 */
case class FooAuthenticatedAction(fooHelper: FooHelper) extends ActionFunction[Request, Request] {
  self =>

    final def apply[A](bodyParser: BodyParser[A])(block: Request[A] => Result): Action[(String, A)] =
        async(bodyParser) { req: Request[A] =>
            Future.successful(block(req))
        }

    final def apply(block: Request[AnyContent] => Result): Action[(String, AnyContent)] =
        apply(BodyParsers.parse.anyContent)(block)

    final def apply(block: => Result): Action[(String, AnyContent)] =
        apply(_ => block)

    final def async(block: => Future[Result]): Action[(String, AnyContent)] =
        async(_ => block)

    final def async(block: Request[AnyContent] => Future[Result]): Action[(String, AnyContent)] =
        async(BodyParsers.parse.anyContent)(block)

    final def async[A](bodyParser: BodyParser[A])(block: Request[A] => Future[Result]): Action[(String, A)] =
        composeAction(
            new Action[(String, A)] {
                def parser = DualBodyParser(parse.tolerantText, composeParser(bodyParser))
                def apply(request: Request[(String, A)]) = try {
                    fooHelper.authenticate(request map (_._1)) match {
                        case Left(error) => failUnauthorized(error)
                        case Right(_key) => invokeBlock(request map (_._2), block)
                    }
                } catch {
                    case e: NotImplementedError => throw new RuntimeException(e)
                    case e: LinkageError => throw new RuntimeException(e)
                }
                override def executionContext = self.executionContext
            }
        )

    /**
     * This produces the Result if authentication fails.
     */
    def failUnauthorized(error: String): Future[Result] =
        Future.successful( Unauthorized(error) )

    protected def composeParser[A](bodyParser: BodyParser[A]): BodyParser[A] = bodyParser

    protected def composeAction[A](action: Action[A]): Action[A] = action

    // we don't use/support this atm
    /**
      override def andThen[Q[_]](other: ActionFunction[R, Q]): ActionBuilder[Q] = new ActionBuilder[Q] 
    **/

    def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: (Request[A]) => Future[Result]) =
        block(request)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The request class only has got one field for body, when a body parser has parsed the request body successfully, that will lead to an instance of Request[A] being created. Normally it's not interesting to have the raw bytes along with the A instance as this would take double the amount of memory for each request.

A body parser can either continue consuming or return early for each chunk of bytes it is fed with.
Maybe you could implement the Hmac validation stuff as a wrapping body parser?

For each chunk of input (Array[Byte]) you would gather up the bytes with the wrapping iteratee/enumeratee. When the end of input comes you trigger the hmac signature calculation/validation on those bytes and can return a BadRequest if it is not valid or push the entire body to the actual body parser.

Comment: If I would have to write `Action(parse.hmacParser) { ...`, that would neither be an acceptable solution for me, since this clearly limits reusability. If it were somehow possible to have an `ActionBuilder` that uses its own `BodyParser` internally and somehow exposes the parsed data, but invokes the wrapped `Action` with the original body parser, that would be acceptable. But I don't see how that would be possible.

Comment: If you had a hmacParser(parse.actualParser) I think you could create an action builder or helper methods to get something like HmacProtected(parse.actualParser) { ...

Comment: Also, you could override composeParser when you create your ActionBuilder and wrap the actual parser with your hmac parser there.

Comment: How _exactly_? I can only return one BodyParser/Iteratee... how should I parse the content without "destroying" the user-defined parser? There is almost no documentation on this topic.

Comment: Well, I dont have time to do it for you and you will need to read up on the iteratees api, but you should be able to create a Enumeratee/Iteratee that will both collect the bytes and pass them to another iteratee. There is quite a lot of docs about the iteratees both in the play doc and in various blogs online, even if no-one has written a solution to your exact problem.